# How to make lattes with plant milk

Tags: latte, foamed-milk

I have just bought a VonChef Milk Frother. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong but the following happens when I put milk into the machine up to the maximum and press go:

1. Hemp - it just seems to heat to a lukewarm level
2. Rice - it doesn't froth the milk and heats to a lukewarm level
3. Coconut - it overflows after like 30 seconds with froth and the milk isn't warm enough

Are my dreams of preparing tasty rice milk lattes not going to happen or should I rather get a Nespresso Milk Frother?

Comment: On a related note, does your machine have two maximum levels? My milk frother (different brand) has two, and filling milk to the upper one would make the machine overflow, as it is only intended for heating-only use of the machine. Perhaps the combination of filling less coconut milk into the machine and using it twice or for a longer time will do the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a high-protein plant milk in order to obtain proper froth as the froth is kept in shape by what are essentially entangled protein molecules. According to google, rice milk only has ~10% of cow milk's protein, which explains why it doesn't work well. Soy milk has pretty much the same percentage of protein as cow milk, so that is worth a try. Coconut milk has ~70% of cow Milk's protein.

Regarding the heating: try a different setting of your frother. Heating should work the same no matter what milk you use.